# Catastrophic backtracking when using PCRE regexp to validate SQL in PHP

Tags: php, regex, pcre, backtracking

I'm trying to validate some SQL in the general form:

```sql
UPDATE `mytable` SET `keyname` = 'keyvalue',
       `a` = 'somestring',
       `b` = 123,
       `c` = NULL
       WHERE `keyname` = 'keyvalue'
```

There are more fields than this. The values will be strings, integers or NULL.

My original regexp is this:

```pcre
(?ix)

^

\s*
UPDATE \s+ `mytable` \s+
SET \s+ `keyname` \s = \s 'keyvalue'
(, \s+
  `[A-Z_]+`  (?# field name)
  \s+ = \s+  (?# equals value)
  (
  -?[0-9]+         (?# an integer, possibly negative)
  |
  '(\\.|''|[^'])*' (?# a string in single quotes)
  |
  NULL             (?# NULL)
  )
)+    (?# one or more such assignments)

\s+ WHERE \s+ `keyname` \s+ = \s+ 'keyvalue'

$
```

This works up to a point. According to https://regex101.com/ it matches in 180 steps.

Unfortunately the real SQL is lengthier than that, for example:

```sql
UPDATE `mytable`
SET `keyname` = 'keyvalue',
`Markup` =
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
''Quisque vel mattis odio, quis iaculis sem.''
Nulla facilisi.
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere
cubilia Curae; Fusce ut dui venenatis, maximus lorem eget, ornare ex.
Aenean tempus pulvinar est, id fringilla enim sagittis id. Mauris finibus
cursus commodo.\r\n\r\n
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere
cubilia Curae; Fusce ut dui venenatis, maximus lorem eget, ornare ex.
Aenean tempus pulvinar est, id fringilla enim sagittis id. Mauris finibus
cursus commodo.\r\n\r\n\r\n
\'Aenean in augue a est vulputate accumsan.\'
Phasellus nulla diam, laoreet a elit non, mattis finibus magna. Phasellus
faucibus iaculis mi sed pulvinar.\r\n
Aliquam non nisl ultricies, aliquam augue vitae, efficitur sapien.
Etiam viverra, magna a laoreet sollicitudin, ipsum erat tincidunt sem, nec
faucibus enim tortor eget massa.
Nunc nisi orci, lacinia vitae dictum et, vestibulum sed metus. ',
`From_Date` = NULL,
`To_Date` = NULL,
`Foo` = '',
`Box_Colour` = NULL,
`Modification_Date` = '2016-09-08 12:30:47',
`Modified_User` = 1,
`Modified_IP` = '192.168.1.1'
WHERE `keyname` = 'keyvalue'
```

That now takes 4301 steps. In fact if you make the Lorem Ipsum larger we reach over 20000 steps.

Also if we introduce an error (to make it not match), for example changing:

```
`Foo` = '',
```

to

```
`Foo` = ''
```

It now crashes with *Catastrophic backtracking*.

I can get rid of the Catastrophic backtracking (to an extent) by making the inner group (the key/value pairs) an atomic group. That is, change:

```regexp
SET \s+ `keyname` \s = \s 'keyvalue'
(, \s+
```

to

```
SET \s+ `keyname` \s = \s 'keyvalue'
(?>, \s+
```

The 20000+ steps on real data are causing the PHP script to crash when run on my target web server. I need to get the steps down to some more realistic value. I can't quite see why there is so much backtracking when it looks like the regexp is reasonably explicit. Fiddling with possessive quantifiers, or atomic groups seems to either do nothing, or cause either the "pass" or "fail" SQL to not match correctly.

Comment: I'm guessing this `( \\ . | '' | [^'] )* ` is the problem. What form of single quoted string do you expect ?

Comment: Also, you _will_ need the `(?s)` modifier to span lines in that quote sub-expression.

Comment: I'm expecting MySQL-style single-quoted strings. There won't be multiple lines in the actual text - it is output from **mysqldump** - multiple lines in the values are replaced by \r\n.

Comment: Regex is just not right tool. E.g. if you try `a` = 'som\''estring', it still accepts it as a valid string. You need a lexer/parser kind of validator. Something like https://github.com/crodas/SQLParser

Comment: It's kind of a moot point there won't be multiple lines in the actual text, you've left the opening for them with `[^']` so, might as well cover the holes with `(?s)` or don't allow with `[^'\r\n]`. Remember, the engine doesn't know anything and will claw it's way to catastrophic backtracking if it can, or you leave openings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit:** For the string sub-expression:
Using the unrolled loop version by @NikiC,
replacing `\s` with `\s*` where needed,
and adding an additional atomic group,
it gets down to a reasonable amount of steps.

https://regex101.com/r/yV5xI7/3

(*edit:* you can also try this version without the unrolled loop
`'(?>[^'\\]+|\\.|'')*'` same difference.  https://regex101.com/r/yV5xI7/5 )

```
 (?si)

 ^ 

 \s* 
 UPDATE \s+ `mytable` \s+ 
 SET \s+ `keyname` \s* = \s* 'keyvalue'

 (?# one or more such key = value  )
 (?>
      \s* , \s* 

      (?# field name )
      ` [A-Z_]+ `  

      (?# equals )
      \s* = \s*  

      (?# value )
      (?>
           (?# an integer, possibly negative )
           -? [0-9]+         
        |  
           (?# or, a string )
           '
           [^'\\]* 
           (?:
                (?: \\ . | '' )
                [^'\\]* 
           )*
           '

           # '
           # (?: [^'\\] | '' | \\ . )*
           # ' 

        |  
           (?# or, literal NULL )
           NULL             
      )
 )+

 \s+ WHERE \s+ `keyname` \s* = \s* 'keyvalue'

 $
```

---

You could try to wrap the quantified core in an atomic group.
Also, you probably need the dot-all modifier for any reference to dot `.`.

And, you should exclude the escape if you are matching it in one of the
alternations in your string sub-expression.
Engines have been known to take the path that matches.
In this case, `[^']` also matches the escape and it looks like
the escape should not be allowed to exist by itself.
And, there may actually be a valid escape + newline sequence, hence the `(?s)`.
I.e. use `(?: \\ . | '' | [^'\\] )*`.

Putting it all together, here is one for ideone

```
/
     (?si)
     ^ \s* UPDATE \s+ `mytable` \s+ SET \s+ `keyname` \s = \s 'keyvalue'
     (?>
          , \s+ ` [A-Z_]+ `
          (?# field name )
          \s+ = \s+ 
          (?# equals value )
          (?:
               -? [0-9]+ 
               (?# an integer, possibly negative )
            |  '
               (?: \\ . | '' | [^'\\] )*
               '
               (?# a string in single quotes )
            |  NULL
               (?# NULL )
          )
     )+
     (?# one or more such assignments )
     \s+ WHERE \s+ `keyname` \s+ = \s+ 'keyvalue' $
/x
```

And one for php

```
'/
     (?si)
     ^ \s* UPDATE \s+ `mytable` \s+ SET \s+ `keyname` \s = \s \'keyvalue\'
     (?>
          , \s+ ` [A-Z_]+ `
          (?# field name )
          \s+ = \s+ 
          (?# equals value )
          (?:
               -? [0-9]+ 
               (?# an integer, possibly negative )
            |  \'
               (?: \\\ . | \'\' | [^\'\\\] )*
               \'
               (?# a string in single quotes )
            |  NULL
               (?# NULL )
          )
     )+
     (?# one or more such assignments )
     \s+ WHERE \s+ `keyname` \s+ = \s+ \'keyvalue\' $
/x'
```

Comment: Often also helpful to "unroll the loop": `'[^'\\\\]*(?:(?:\\\\.|'')[^'\\\\]*)*'` Probably doesn't matter given the atomic group.

Comment: I never gave it any thought because of the multiple alternations. I wonder how that would bench though given still an alternation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately your regexp still gets up to 20000+ steps if you copy/paste the middle of the target string a few times (ie. around 5000 characters of SQL). Maybe regexp just isn't the tool for the job.

Comment: It's definitely the string sub-expression causing all the steps. It can be reduced by %30 steps if you use the unroll loop of NikiC suggested. The irony is that allowing both `''` and `\'` causes all the headaches because `''` can be a complete string, thus the backtracking. Usually only one or the other should be allowed.

Comment: Here: https://regex101.com/r/yV5xI7/1  - I halved the number of steps by reordering the string literal, but then that started being weird. It would match and then not match.

Comment: It's a lot fewer steps, but if you make the "value" part capturing, you see it is capturing too much. I'm not certain, but it might lend to SQL injection if the test isn't accurate. I was hoping that each key/value pair would be a capture on their own (I don't need the capture, but it's the principle that the regexp is working correctly).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122943/discussion-between-nick-gammon-and-sln).

Comment: No, the _value_ part is delimited by an equals sign `=` which can only be matched in a key = value part _OR_ = could be matched in a string. There is really no other way the engine could match it. I'll update the post with this regex.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Thanks very much! It is down to about 900 steps compared to 20000 before.

Comment: @NikiC, you should post your own answer; unrolling the loop makes all the difference.  The atomic group doesn't help because all the backtracking occurs inside it, and excluding the backslash has no effect in this case (though he definitely should have been doing that).

Comment: @NickGammon - You're welcome! @AlanMoore - the unrolled loop just displayed what's really wrong. `'(?>[^'\\]+|\\.|'')*'` it's too many steps because the class matched one character at a time. To smooth that out, just need to quantify it and enclose it in a atomic group. Takes even less steps.